# PhpExcel Dynamic Header in first Row

Tags: phpexcel

I have below SQL and I want to write field values in first row and rest of the row and values. How do I achieve using PHPEXCEL.

Can someone post full example.

I found so many example how to write fixed rows when you know the field name but without knowing field name I like to print header in first row and rest as values.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM uam_user";
```

Comment: I am using EXCEL 2010.

Comment: Get the result of your query as an associative array, and the array keys will be your column names